# Linking emulator on different platform

Tags: ios, android, emulation, my-boy

I am wondering whether is it possible to link an emulator on Android (myBoy!) to an emulator on iOS (gba4ios) since both emulators do provide a linking feature.

I have never owned an iPhone before so I could not try it myself, and I couldn't find any relevant threads on the Internet.

Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: Do you mean using the GBA "link cable" or do you mean transferring your saves between devices?

Comment: @Robotnik i mean the former. Eg transferring pokemon within two instance of emulator but in two different OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think linking them is going to be particularly easy, transferring files between your phones using a computer is more doable.

What you can do to get the data from one phone to the other:

1. Find the save on the android phone.
2. Copy to the computer.
3. Iff the emulators use incompatible save files: Convert from one type to the other.
4. Copy to the other phone.

Now if we're talking about a game like Pokémon, where you want to link to trade, look up if your emulator provides linking features. Launch two instances on the iPhone using your old and new save file and link them up. Then you can trade the monsters (in my example), or whatever else you wanted to do.